# How to pass clientId of a control in Repeater to JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a repeater having two columns. In first column i have an image button on click of which i am calling a javascript function.

In the second column i have a label. I want to pass the client id of this label to the javascript function called on click on ImageButton.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptElements" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tdElementType" runat="server">
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgShow" runat="Server" Visible="false" OnClientClick="return DisplayElementDetails(this);" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <asp:Label ID="lblElementDetails" Text='<%# Eval("ElementDetails")%>' runat="server" />
            </td>
                        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Show your javascript function.

Comment: Its just a blank function, i just want id of label lblElementDetails. So that i can hide or display label.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. 
I added following code to the javascript function:

```
function DisplayElementDetails(obj)
            {
                var name = obj.id.substring(0,(obj.name.length)-7) + "lblElementDetails"
                var obj = document.getElementById(name);
                obj.style.display = 'none';
                return false;
            }
```

and set the style for label control

```
<asp:Label ID="lblElementDetails" Text='<%# Eval("ElementDetails")%>' runat="server" style="display:block" />
```

Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by Jquery. Add CSSclass to button and label for selecting them using CSS selectors

```
<td id="tdElementType" runat="server">
   <asp:ImageButton ID="imgShow" runat="Server" Visible="false" CssClass="showButton" /></td>
<td>
   <asp:Label ID="lblElementDetails" Text='<%# Eval("ElementDetails")%>' runat="server"   CssClass="lblElement"/>
</td>
```

Reference JQuery on aspx page and call function on click event of image button

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".showButton").click(function(){

                 $(".lblElement").toggle();
             });
        });
    </script>
```